# Continuous functions on bounded closed interval is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

The linked proof is in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863270/contiuous-function-on-a-closed-bounded-interval-is-uniformly-continuous-dont-u). It first assumed
$$(1)\quad\quad |f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\geq \varepsilon_0\;\;\;\;n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Then after finding convergent sub-subsequences, $\{x_{n_{k_j}}\}$ and $ \{y_{n_{k_j}}\}$, the proof then says it follows from (1) that
$$(2) \quad\quad |f(x)-f(y)|\geq \varepsilon_0.$$

**Questions**:

1. The (2), in the proof, seems to now claim $\forall x,y\in I$. Is this true?
2. Additionally, how do the sub subsequences play a role in finishing the proof to find the contradiction? Was it used in showing that (2)? If this is the case, I don't know then.

Any help is appreciated as it is not obvious for me, thank you!

Comment: You should first write down in a clear way all the steps you have made

Comment: steps? @blamethelag I am not sure I understand your question as the steps (and i guess the implicit ones) of the proof are in the linked post (Then I guess I am looking where the implicit things are hidden to then assume the second line). Would you clarify what you mean?

Comment: In my opinion what you wrote on your post is hasty and confused. You should rephrase it in a more clear way so that you understand what is happening.

Comment: edited @blamethelag

Comment: Oh my sorry. I meant you should do the proof from the begining to where you are stuck. Like perform the redaction, introduct the objects etc